# Setting up Microsoft VS Code for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was following article on official website , but I had to make some changes(workspace and folder name). I already have MinGW(I installed it along with codeblocks and it works) installed so I skipped this step, Though I noticed that article has mentioned minGW64. Then I simply pasted code for helloworld and tasks.json from the article to overwrite the code which was generated automatically. I had to change directory 'command' argument.
And then I buid it and ran into error saying:

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:C:\Users\Schoo\Projects\Assignments.vscode\tasks.json: file format not recognized; treating
> as linker script
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:C:\Users\Schoo\Projects\Assignments.vscode\tasks.json:1: syntax error
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The terminal process "C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe '-g', 'C:\Users\Schoo\Projects\Assignments.vscode\tasks.json', '-o', 'C:\Users\Schoo\Projects\Assignments.vscode\tasks.exe'" terminated with exit code: 1.

And the I was Debugging, so it said: "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.

```
"version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell", // I remember there was something in place of shell.
```

Is this happening because I didn't install minGW64?Or its something else? Should I replace Ming32 with Ming64?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you edit in a link to the article you're following? You shouldn't be trying to actually compile tasks.json, only the .cpp file. (What is tasks.json - a VS Code makefile?)

Comment: Looking at the error message it seems you are passing tasks.json to the MinGW linker, which is then complaining that it doesn't recognise the file format. This indicates that you've done something seriously wrong in configuring VSCode, but I don't think it's any of the things you are suggesting.

Comment: Even if you manage to get it working, you definitely should replace MinGW with MinGW-w64.

Comment: @Rup tasks.json is a system wide configuration file for VSCode. We get hundreds of questions from beginners who have configured it incorrectly.

Comment: mingw-w64 forked from mingw in 2007. You should probably consider them entirely separate by now.

Comment: Presumably you have your filename set to current file in tasks.json? If so you need to make sure your cpp file is the active tab before running the build. If you're a novice programmer you'd be much better off with visual studio which is a lot easier to use than code

Comment: @jon tasks.json is not system wide. Every VSCode workspace can have its own tasks.json in it's .vscode folder.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the info. I'm learning VSCode just from the questions here.

Comment: But why tasks.json is important? I deleted tasks.json file and then ran my code and it worked. All I need is just an environment which can build executables, so that my professor need not copy paste it somewhere else, where my code might throw bugs.